# Continuously Generating Random Coordinates in a Text File Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, real-time, text-extraction

Is there a way to continuously add random coordinates to a text file using python? (UPDATED)

```
import random
import threading

#Open a file named numbersmake.txt.
outfile = open('new.txt', 'w')

def coordinate():
    threading.Timer(0.0000000000001, coordinate).start ()
    x = random.randint(0,10000)
    y = random.randint(0,10000)
    outfile.write("{},{}\n".format(x, y))

coordinate()

#Close the file.
outfile.close()
print('The data is now the the new.txt file')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code it looks like you are just trying to generate 12,000 random coordinates in one shot and exit. If this is the case why would you want to thread it? You would only need to thread if you plan to do something else with your program while the thread is dealing with collecting coordinates.

Maybe if your coordinate generation were triggered by some external, unpredictable event it might make sense. Otherwise, if you are really just generating a finite set of coordinates as quickly as possible, I think your range solution is fine.

More detail on what you are really trying to do would help craft a better solution.

Comment: Correct. Right now the range is generating 12,000 random coordinates in one shot. I want to get rid of the range that generates these 12,000 coordinates and use continuous threading instead so I am getting continuous coordinates for a real time graph. How do I do this?

Comment: Is the graph also drawn from this same program? Is there any restriction on the maximum number of coordinates? It would be risky to have a thread generate random numbers to a file without bound or any sort of delay between coordinate generation. Is it possible that you don't need to store the coordinates? That is, if you generate the coordinates with one thread you could put them on a queue for action by the graph-drawing thread?

Comment: No need to store coordinates. I was generating the coordinates with one python file, writing it to a text and reading it to another python file which graphs the coordinates. If there is an easier way of doing this please let me know! Ideally, the graph needs to show 20ish points at a time with 100 frames per second and we get rid of those points.

Comment: The point is that there is no reason to thread your generator program unless it is also doing some thing else (e.g. drawing a graph) too. If you want to collect unlimited coordinates then you would probably want to integrate your 'generator' and 'drawer' otherwise you may run into concurrency issues with your data file trying to be written and read at the same time. I think you should integrate the two pieces assuming they are intended to only work together and not as general utilities that can be used elsewhere.

Comment: It's hard to give you an 'answer' without seeing how all the pieces work. However, it sounds like the Threading and Queue modules would work for you. Maybe this link can help: https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/

Comment: Have to have two pieces in order to plug into driver later down the road so I cannot integrate the two. The first python file is acting as a driver right now until ready to be plugged in.

Comment: Is the idea that you want to generate coordinates until requested to stop? If so, there's a real risk of filling up your filesystem since I presume your consumer doesn't delete any of the data in the file. You might look at using a named pipe (assuming Linux/Unix) for IPC. Either way you probably need to somehow slow down the rate at which your data is generated.

Comment: I would like to generate coordinates, throw them out and generate new coordinates and so on. I will run that 100 frames per second. There is no need to store these coordinates and really I could just repeat the process with range, like I had before, since it is being pulled into a new driver later down the road.

Comment: You want to batch them in 12,000 or so? If so your current method of range is good. I see no reason for the complexity of threading. I would only recommend looking at names pipes (see: os.mkfifo) which can be used like files within your python files but actually reside in memory. They're a better way to share data between two separate processes on the same machine. Sockets are another option but probably only if you foresee these processes being across separate machines. If they'll always be on the same machine pipes are probably easier.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Can you upvote this if it was helpful? I'm new to the site and am trying to get more privileges by participating. Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted it but until I reach 15, it doesn't count. I am new to the site as well and am at 13 now.

Comment: Since it's your question your could probably accept the answer if it's acceptable.

Comment: I have 15 now. Just did. Thanks again. Enjoy your weekend!